# Interop IStream derived class – redundant methods?

Tags: .net

I have a .NET interop with three interfaces that "implements" IStream i.e.
    [mscorlib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream 
And they add a few methods of their own. Each interface also has a class.

I had to do some modifying (round tripping) and as I was perusing the .IL,
I noticed how these IStream derived interfaces and classes are implemented. 
All the IStream methods are declared along with the additional methods.

In a Win32 ( _TLB unit ) I don't have to do this. An interface derived from,
in this case, IStream, needs only to declare the additional methods. The same for
the class which implements the DefaultInterface method.

This means in the interop there are six different declarations that include all the IStream methods.
Is this really necessary? Is there a way to avoid having all these seemingly redundant
declarations?

bilm

Answer (score 1):

> In a Win32 ( _TLB unit ) I don't have to do this

Well, you do, it just isn't as explicit as it is in C#.  COM does not support implementation inheritance, only interface inheritance.  Which means that when you implement a coclass, you have to provide the implementation of *all* of the methods of *all* of the interfaces that the coclass inherits.  COM supports aggregation but that isn't very useful.

The C++ language models interfaces as pure abstract classes.  And supports multiple inheritance, very convenient in COM.  Inheriting from an interface only requires adding the *extra* methods, the inherited abstract methods come along without having to repeat them.  Just like they do with an abstract base class in C#.  So that's probably where your "I don't have to do this" observation comes from.

It works differently in a CLR language, interfaces behave like "true" interfaces and are implemented as stubs with no demand that the methods are present at a particular v-table slot.  And no support for multiple inheritance.  The CLR itself provides the implementation for IUnknown and IDispatch, no need to repeat the methods in those interfaces.  But if you derive an interface from a non-trivial other interface then you are forced to *repeat* the declarations of the inherited methods in order to get the v-table correct and exactly match the COM v-table order.  And of course, just as in C++, you have to implement them as well.

This is fairly annoying and error prone, but unavoidable.  A lot of this pain disappears when you have a type library and this can all be auto-generated.  Never discount the possibility of just generating one with midl.exe from an IDL file so you don't need the C# declarations, even if the COM component doesn't provide one.

Comment: I really appreciate the explanation because I could not decipher it
from the ECMA-335 or ISO/IEC 23271 or any of the other documentation I have on CIL. I was looking for ways to trim the fat but in this case I now understand the istream methods are necessary.